# Unknown indicator of package specification

Tags: pcb-design, datasheet, layout

I am creating the footprint of an IC, and the manufacturer has specified this below:

[image: Package outline]

I cannot figure out what C0.3 stands for. Is it the length of the diagonal? If it helps, according to another drawing for this rectangular pad, X=1.55mm and Y=1.40mm

Comment: the ends of the cutoff corner appear to line up with the centerlines of the circular pad rows and columns

Comment: @jsotola Nice catch, thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

C stands for **chamfer** in mechanical drawings.

C0.3 means that the chamfer is 45° and 0.3mm is the dimension as shown below on the X axis (also 0.3mm along the Y axis):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I expect from corner triangle hypotenuse of 0.3mm and overall dimension of 1.55 mm or 20% of the side, that makes sense from the photo.

Thus you can compute each side as 0.21 mm of the corner.  That appears to prevent solder bridging from the corner during reflow for this heat/ power pad.

Comment: It seems my intuition was wrong and chamfer dimension is = X or Y and not Hypotenuse